# How to prevent a hover component from distorting its parent component in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, components

I have a component that is shown on hover. I'm using it inside another component that has some text content. When the hover component is shown, it distorts (pushes) the contents of the component it is used in. Basically, I want to stop the hover component from interfering with its parent component. Here is my code:

LanguageOptions (hover component) styling:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const LanguagesWrapper = styled.div`
  // removed padding: 0.3rem;
  background-color: #b0b2b7;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1; /* Add flex-grow property to expand vertically */
  gap: 0.8rem;
`;

export const StyledLanguagesTitle = styled.p`
  padding: 0.3rem; // added padding here;
  font-size: ${({theme}) => theme.typography.fontSize.medium};
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
  &:hover {
    background-color: #526d82;
  }
`;

export const ButtonForReferenceLink = styled.button<{
  icon: string;
}>`
  position: relative;
  width: 1.3rem;
  height: 1.3rem;
  background-image: url(${({icon}) => icon});
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  :first-of-type {
    height: 1.1rem;
  }
`;
```

References styling:

```
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';


export const StyledWrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 200px;
  width: 98%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
  gap: 0.5rem;
`;

export const StyledTitle = styled.h2<{type: boolean}>`
  font-size: ${({theme}) => theme.typography.fontSize.mediumLarge};
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  color: ${({theme, type}) => (type ? '#e0e0e0' : theme.colors.blue)};
`;

export const StyledInnerWrapper = styled.div<{type: boolean}>`
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 30rem;
  padding-right: 1.3rem;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  /* Custom scrollbar styles */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0.2
    ); /* Add a little bit of opaq gray to the scrollbar background */
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: ${({type}) =>
      type
        ? '#ff6363'
        : '#779199'}; /* Set the color of the scrollbar bar to red */
    border-radius: 5px;
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color: #c70000; /* Change the color of the scrollbar bar when hovering over it */
  }
`;

export const ReferenceItem = styled.div<{darkMode: boolean}>`
  display: flex;
  background-color: ${({theme, darkMode}) =>
    darkMode ? 'grey' : theme.colors.blueWithOpacity};
  padding: ${({theme}) => theme.spacing.small};
  border-radius: 0.6rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: fit-content;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  gap: 1rem;
  
`;

export const Content = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0.3rem;
  
`;

export const ButtonsWrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 3rem;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0.3rem;
  gap: 0.8rem;
`;

export const StyledText = styled.p<{small?: boolean, darkMode:boolean}>`

  font-size: ${({theme, small}) =>
    small
      ? theme.typography.fontSize.small
      : theme.typography.fontSize.mediumSmall};

  ${({small}) =>
    small &&
    css`
      font-style: italic;
      padding-top: 0.5rem;
      padding-bottom: 0.4rem;
    `}

  ${({theme}) => theme.breakpoints.up('sm')} {
    font-size: ${({theme, small}) =>
      small
        ? theme.typography.fontSize.small
        : theme.typography.fontSize.medium};
  }
  color: ${({theme, darkMode}) =>
   darkMode ? 'white'  : 'black' }; /* Add the desired color value here */
`;

export const ButtonForReferenceLink = styled.button<{icon: string}>`
  position: relative;
  width: 1.3rem;
  height: 1.3rem;
  background-image: url(${({icon}) => icon});
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;

  :first-of-type {
    height: 1.1rem;
  }
`;
```

Gif:[image]

I tried some CSS on it but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Looking at your GIF, it appears to me that the text content has to be repositioned to make room for the hover drop-down. I suggest that you either use padding on the right side so that the text flow isn't affected by the drop-down, or have the drop-down positioned on top of the text.

Answer (score 0):

**Is it possible to solve with CSS**

*html*

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="chilled">
 ... some element
</div>
</div>
```

*css*

```css
/* position: relative; is positioned relative to its normal position. */ 
.parent{
position: relative;
}
/* position: absolute; is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor. */ 
.chilled{
position: absolute;
}
```

CSS Position property is used to place an element behind another without affecting the other elements position
Learn more [Here](https://blog.hubspot.com/website/css-position#:%7E:text=The%20CSS%20position%20property%20is,final%20location%20of%20the%20element.)